# Connecting modern PSU to very old Acer motherboard

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I just purchased a new PSU (be quiet! System Power 9 400W) to put into my computer. I did this, because the old PSU just had 220W and I want to put in a different GPU thich has a higher power demand. Now the PSU arrived and I discovered that it does not have the correct plugs to connect to my mother board. The PSU has 6+2 Pin, 20+4 Pin and 4 Pin connectors. My mother board has a 12 Pin connector (see image circled in red). So can I just connect the 20 Pin cable to the 12 Pin connector of the motherboard or buy an adapter or connect two 6 pin cables to the 12 pin connector? Or is the PSU entirely incompatible with the Motherboard? Also there are these weird connectors on the motherboard (circled in blue) that I don't even know what they're good for. Are they important/necessary?

Edit: the motherboard is an Acer H11H4.

[image: Motherboard connectors][image: PSU cable]

Comment: Your original power supply is not an ATX power supply.  The PSU you purchased is not compatible with your Acer device.

Comment: @Ramhound oh great... I‘m so stupid. What is then if not ATX?

Comment: PC OEMs are notorious for using non-standard parts only they use since they purchase millions.  I honestly don't know the standard Acer uses, I just know, it's not ATX based on the information you provided.

Comment: @Max You will have to give us some more details about the motherboard.

Comment: @Tonny I added the motherboard model. Or what information would you need?

Comment: @Max Trust Acer to do something non-standard. That motherboard is available in a Rev1 and a Rev2. The Rev2 has a normal ATX power-supply. The Rev1 not. You have the Rev1. Do you have a manual that shows the pinout of the white connectors? That would make clear if a straight up conversion from a normal ATX power-supply would be possible.

Comment: @tonny unfortunately I dont. Got that computer from a friend who got it fron his office... it‘s hard to find in depth information on the main board

Answer (score 4):

> can I just connect the 20 Pin cable to the 12 Pin connector of the motherboard

No! As far as I know, it doesn't work.

> buy an adapter

I noticed that your old motherboard has a 12-pin PSU connector. So you will certainly need [this adapter](https://www.moddiy.com/products/Acer-PSU-Main-Power-24-Pin-to-12-Pin-Adapter-Cable-30cm.html) that will help you convert from 24-pin to 12-pin male connector.

As of the cable you marked with the blue circle, it's the AT motherboard power connector.

[image]

Image source: [Robotz.com](http://wiki.robotz.com/index.php/PC_Power_Supply_Voltage_Data_and_Connector_Types)

> The original PC starting in 1981 used two cables (Molex 90331) to connect the power supply to the motherboard. They connected side by side into the motherboard, and they could easily be reversed accidentally, or inverted which will result in damage to the motherboard. When connecting them to the motherboard it was important to observe the "black to black" rule.

To use this AT connector with your old motherboard, use [this adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EDGS0KI), which helps to transform from 20 pin connector to AT connector.

If you only has one 20 pin connector, use [this splitter](https://www.moddiy.com/products/Power-Supply-ATX-20-Pin-24-Pin-Cable-Y-Splitter.html).

Comment: So what about the blue circle marked connector. How can I connect those to the new powersupply?

Comment: This one may help you. https://www.amazon.com/20-Pin-Power-Supply-Adapter-Cable/dp/B01EDGS0KI

Comment: But if I need one 20 Pin power supply to connect to the 12 Pin connector and another 20 Pin one to connect to these P8 P9 connectors, i'm one 20 Pin power supply short....

Comment: Why not use this? https://www.moddiy.com/products/Power-Supply-ATX-20-Pin-24-Pin-Cable-Y-Splitter.htmlYou don't need both of them. One more thing: "Remember to install the P8 and P9 plugs so that the black wires are side by side. Installing them on the wrong receptacle can damage both the motherboard and the power supply. "

Comment: Are ypu sure, I don‘t need both? Because with the original PSU, both of them were connected...

Comment: In that case, use this one: https://www.moddiy.com/products/Power-Supply-ATX-20-Pin-24-Pin-Cable-Y-Splitter.html

Comment: I have updated all the information to the answer to avoid making this comment longer.